# how do i add number and string to my django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

How can I add a number and text randomly to my `model.py`. I have a website with an user profile in it. When a user subscribes, it will generate a random text and a number to the user profile and that will serve the user like an ID till the subscription is over. Below is my code -

##models.py

```
 def plan_id():
    plan_id=[]
    for i in range(5):
        alpha=random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
        num=random.choice(string.digits)
        plan_id.append(alpha)
        plan_id.append(num)
    y = "".join(str(x)for x in plan_id)
    return y
    


class Patient(models.Model):
    STATE_CHOICES=(
        (True, u'Yes'),
        (False, u'No'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name="patient")
    subscribe = models.BooleanField(default=True, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    plan_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, blank=True, default=plan_id)
```

##views.py

@login_required

```
def patient(request):
    context = {
        'patient': Patient.objects.all()
    
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/patient.html', context)
```

##template.html

```
      <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
         <fieldset class="form-group">
             <legend class="border-bottom mb-4 h4 text-center center">Your Email</legend>
           <legend class=" mb-4 h3 center text-center">{{ user.email }}</legend>
         </fieldset>
         <div class="form-group text-center center">
          {% if not user.patient.subscribe %}
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Subscribe</button>
{% else %}
{% if user.patient.subscribe %}
  <button class="btn btn-danger" disabled type="submit">Subscribed</button>

  <p>Thanks For Subscribing here is your Plan ID {{ user.patient.plan_id }} </p>
{% endif %}
{% endif %}
         </div>
      </form>
```

[image: here is what am talking about]

Comment: Confused exactly on what you are trying to do. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33588668/how-to-set-a-random-integer-as-the-default-value-for-a-django-charfield) also

Comment: You want a 10 char random string; In `plan_id()` you can simply return y at the end.

Comment: actually i dont know if that code is corect i was just trying to add a e.g random password for every users,automaticallly without me adding it manually through the admin

Comment: @Ben will i  just return y ???like that

Comment: @Chosenbrain - Yes, `y` is already a 10 char random string. Try it out!

Comment: @Ben i tried it but shows nothing

Comment: @Chosenbrain can you share the template code as well ?

Comment: @AniketMaithani this is my templates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django has a built in fields for this,its very cool  [cool stuff for the question just add it to your model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield)

```
plan_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, help_text="Unique ID for every particular patient for every profile")
```